# Finding duplicates in mongo

Tags: mongodb

In the MongoDB I want to search for all duplicates on a certain field `ownersEmailAddress` with or without upper letters (any combination of letter).

In the mongodb compass when I known the value i can use

```
{ownersEmailAddress: /john@bmw.com/i}
```

but how can I do it without knowing specific value (search every ownersEmailAddress proeprty) with any case for duplicates?

I don't want to compare with value john@bmw.com, just all duplicates on this field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query

- group by lowercase email

I dont know what you need as expected output so i added

- count of duplicates
- all the duplicate docs
- all the firstNames of duplicates
- all the firstNames and emails of duplicates

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70833128-1-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group":
  {"_id":{"$toLower":"$ownersEmailAddress"},
   "dupl-count":{"$sum":1},
   "dupl-docs":{"$push":"$$ROOT"},
   "dupl-firstNames":{"$push":"$firstName"},
   "dupl-firstNamesEmails":
   {"$push":
    {"firstName":"$firstName", "email":"$ownersEmailAddress"}}}}])
```

Comment: will this returns data with any letter case,  not just lower case?

Comment: yes, the lowercase is just for grouping, data are collected un-changed in dupl-emails, see the example, i think you need this , if this is not what you need, if you can add example data and expected results

Comment: how can I select only firstname from this dupl-email collections? In this example selects whole objects. Firstname is a valid property name in the document or email address instead.

Comment: i added some more, i cant be sure what you need unless you give the expected output, but i think this will work for you. Keep the accumulators you need, and delete the rest

Answer (score 0):

Using [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) you can do that

```
db.user.aggregate([  
    {$group: {
        _id: {ownersEmailAddress: "$ownersEmailAddress"},

        count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: I don't want to compare with value john@bmw.com, just all duplicates on this field

Comment: I update my answer pls check !

Comment: @MayurVaghasiya Search needs to be case insensitive. So first we should project the email with lower/upper case email and then we should do the grouping.